# Angular2: strange vague error when trying to get Json from server using a rest service

Tags: rest, angular

I am trying to get a product from a local server using an angular2 rest service.  When I do the GET I get the following error.  I can get the item from the server using the Insomnia rest client so I know the issue is not with the server.  i've also checked the url and made sure there's no errors there.  Any idea what else I can check?  i'm using ng-cli to run the app...

my error:

```
http://10.60.160.34/BRMServices/WebEnquiry//POSEnquiry/293
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
app.component.ts:32
failureServer error
```

my rest service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions  } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from  "rxjs/Rx";
import { ProductModel } from "../models/product.model";

//import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
//import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
//import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw' 

@Injectable()
export class RestService {
  public API_URL: string = "http://10.60.160.34/BRMServices/WebEnquiry/";
  private headers: Headers;
  private options: RequestOptions;

  constructor(private http: Http){
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    this.headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
  }

  getProduct(barcode: string): Observable<ProductModel> {
    return this.http.get(this.API_URL + "/POSEnquiry/" + barcode, this.options)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }  
}
```

my app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RestService } from "./services/rest.service";
import { ProductModel } from "./models/product.model";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  product: ProductModel;
  constructor(private restService: RestService){}

  submitBarcode(barcode: HTMLInputElement){
    this.restService.getProduct(barcode.value)
    .subscribe((res) => {
      //product = res;
      console.log(res);
    }, (res) => {
      console.log("failure" + res);
    });
    //console.log("product: " + product);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be the RequestOptions variable.  When I replaced options with headers in the get request it worked with no issues...